# Testcafe: the 'src' and 'browser' options from the configuration file will be ignored

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am new to testcafe and trying to understand how testcafe scripts are being run with an existing framework I am working on. Whenever we run a script, browser takes 2 minutes to launch and it seem to be a remote browser and not local browser as I can't interact with this browser during run time (when needed).

Here are the questions I have.

1. What is causing browser launch delay (currently it is taking 1.5-2 minutes to launch)
2. How can I force testcafe to run test on a local browser on my machine. I updated path in configuration file but it is always ignoring what is specified in this file and showing message mentioned in the (title of this post) when the test is started.

Comment: 1. Please share the testcafe version.  I faced the browser delay in one of the earlier versions, but the recent ones are good.  1.19.0, 1.20.0.
2. Does the package.json have any runconfig listed which could be triggering the headless browser?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have checked the version and I see different version using the command vs what is in changelog file in Testcafe package.


#1. command npm -version testcafe. It returned 8.31.
#2. Opened testcafe module and checked change log. There it shows 1.19.0
#3. In project Package.json - we specified it under devDependencies  for version 1.18.4
So I am not really sure why it is showing 8.3.1 instead of 1.19

Answer (score 0):

> What is causing browser launch delay (currently it is taking 1.5-2 minutes to launch)

It's very strange. The browser started immediately. Could you please create a simple example and share it here?

> How can I force testcafe to run test on a local browser on my machine.

See instructions [here](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402830/guides/basic-guides/run-tests#cli).